# Firebase: Using auth.uid as a userId - that's bad right?

Tags: javascript, security, firebase, firebase-security

Tools: Firebase

Issue: Security with completely client-side code and exposing unique Ids

I've been really scratching my head on how to create a system to uniquely Id a user for basic user-user interactions.

Common examples - direct messaging a friend, adding a new contact ect...

There has to be a unique id being passed out to clients in order to establish those types of connections

The reason I am so tripped up is because **in my mind I'm not suppose to be exposing any users uids(for security reasons it seems sketchy)** and therefore I would need to give a user multiple unique ids( one for a group, or for each connection,ect).

So am I wrong and I can use the uid so long as I set up security rules? I'm sure there has to be be a super simple answer to this one.

Comment: I recently answered a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342681/firebase-uid-as-qr-code-tag/33347706#33347706

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yea that answer helped a lot! So it's logically to use that to identify the user  in order to pass them messages or resources?

Comment: Yup, uids are used everywhere to identify users.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks a million you are always suuuper helpful!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use Firebase UID as QR code tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342681/is-it-safe-to-use-firebase-uid-as-qr-code-tag)