# If I set up my Firestore rules like this, can a user bypass it if they know the userDocID of someone else?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've set up my Firestore rules like this:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    ///Rules:
    ///Only the owner can modify their stuff under the Users collection     
    match /users/{uid} { 
      allow read, write, delete: if isOwner(uid) && emailVerified();
    }
    
    match /users/{uid}/groups/{groupID} { 
        allow read, write, delete: if isOwner(uid) && emailVerified();
    }
    
    match /users/{uid}/friends/{friendID} { 
        allow read, write, delete: if isOwner(uid) && emailVerified();
    }
    
    match /users/{uid}/notifications/{notifID} { 
        allow read, write, delete: if isOwner(uid) && emailVerified();
    }
    
    /// Functions ///
    function emailVerified() { 
      return request.auth.token.email_verified; ///returns true if email is verified
    }

    function isOwner(uid) {
      return request.auth.uid == uid
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, the idea is this: a user can only modify records in the sub-collections within their user document. The sub-collections are groups, friends, and notifications. The rules will check the incoming `request.auth.uid` and see if it matches the `uid` in `users/{uid}` before allowing them to modify any sub-collection.

I'm just now realizing that within the `friends` collection I'm storing the `uid` of those friends. So now I'm worried that there might be a security risk. If a user downloads their friends list, they will receive the `uid` of those friends. Could a malicious user then use the `uid` to impersonate that friend and modify their firestore records?

Comment: Knowing the UID of a user is not enough to impersonate them. See my answer here for more on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342681/is-it-safe-to-use-firebase-uid-as-qr-code-tag

Comment: For maintaining friendship relationships this structure allows an authentication user that anyone else is their friend. To make friendship bidirectional, you'll typically want to build in a confirmation step where the other UID must also add my UID to their list of friends.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen in that case I guess it all comes down to whether or not Firebase auth can be circumvented somehow. I haven't read anything online that there are any vulnerabilities, so that's good news on that front. I don't quite understand what you mean with the first sentence of your second comment. Right now I have Firestore triggers that make both users' friend records update according to how the relationship changes, so I'm assuming that is in line with what you're saying about bi-directional friendships.

Comment: Sorry, that first sentence was mangled indeed: in your data structure any (authenticated) user can claim that anyone else is their friend. You typically want to only acknowledge the friendship once it's mutual, so once both user A has written the the UID of user B in their data **and** user B has written the UID of user A *their* data.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ah right. You might have just saved my life. Thanks Puf!